# How can I export all dependent functions in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, export, computer-vision

I am using MATLAB 2015a but my code needs to be compatible with 2014a version. Therefore I am looking for a solution, if there is any, to export 'fitcecoc' function with all its dependencies, which have been added in MATLAB 2014b.

In addition I have to tell that I do not have access to modify files inside 2014a, so all those functions which I would like to export needs to work straight from my workspace.

Comment: i think there is no way, that's why you have to PAY for the upgrade (unless you have paid annual fee)